# OneSignal plugin doesn't work

Tags: typescript, ionic3, onesignal

First of all, could someone explain me how OneSignal works? Can I use it to receive notifications when someone insert something in my Firebase Database?

I need to use OneSignal plugin in my Ionic App. I installed it by

```
 ionic cordova plugin add onesignal-cordova-plugin
```

Then I added in my `app.components.ts` this

```
  // OneSignal Code start:
  // Enable to debug issues:
  // window["plugins"].OneSignal.setLogLevel({logLevel: 4, visualLevel: 4});

  var notificationOpenedCallback = function(jsonData) {
    console.log('notificationOpenedCallback: ' + JSON.stringify(jsonData));
  };

  window["plugins"].OneSignal
    .startInit("58c4f617-632a-.....", "5...")
    .handleNotificationOpened(notificationOpenedCallback)
    .endInit();
```

But I got an error when I launch `ionic serve`, it says

```
Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'OneSignal' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'OneSignal' of undefined
```

I searched all the web but it seems the procedure to include this plugin is the previous so i can't undertand why it doesn't work. I've looked in my plugin folder too in the `android.json` and `fetch.json` files. I can post them here.

android.json

```
"onesignal-cordova-plugin": {
  "PACKAGE_NAME": "io.ionic.starter"
}
```

fetch.json

```
"onesignal-cordova-plugin": {
"source": {
  "type": "registry",
  "id": "onesignal-cordova-plugin"
}
```

I've installed `"@ionic-native/onesignal": "^4.6.0",` too but I can't understand if I need it too.

Comment: delete .sourcemaps and www folder from the project and then run ionic serve again

Comment: It doesn't work

Comment: try by adding npm package and run serve again: npm install --save @ionic-native/onesignal

Comment: I updated the post writing i've already tried to install that package, but it gives me the same error

Comment: Did you fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I am using cordova and I just fixed the issue downgrading the onesignal-cordova-plugin version to 2.2.2